# Spaces in the spool even with right set parameters

Tags: unix, set, whitespace, ksh, spool

My spool has a problem; i've written these sets:

```
    echo "SET COLSEP #@"                                                       >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}       
    echo "SET PAGESIZE 0"                                                      >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL} 
    echo "SET TERMOUT ON"                                                      >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}
    echo "SET TRIMOUT ON"                                                      >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}
    echo "SET LINESIZE 1000"                                                   >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}        
    echo "SET FEEDBACK OFF"                                                    >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}        
    echo "SET TRIMSPOOL ON"                                                    >> ${FILE_SPOOL_SQL}
```

but the output still has spaces:

```
PART_ONE    #@2.26453E+20@#DATE_FIRST     #@13-JUN-13@#13-JUN-13 09.50.00.000000 PM
```

I want something like:

```
PART_ONE#@2.26453E+20@#DATE_FIRST#@13-JUN-13@#13-JUN-13 09.50.00.000000 PM
```

How can i resolve it?

Comment: what's your sql select statement?

Comment: i'm making an insert.

Comment: the output of an insert has spaces ?

Comment: i've wrong, i'm making a select sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has been aswered [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1726449413350):

> It is trimming it -- its just that sqlplus formats the results into columns based on 
>   their widths.  sqlplus is a reporting tool -- it likes to print things "pretty".

So you need to format your own select statement.

Comment: mmh, so do you think that the problem is because my select takes everything (SELECT * FROM ....) ?

Comment: yes that's why I asked you in the comment about your select statement :)